# GetTempFileName() and saving to the AppData folder

Tags: c#, wpf

In the below code, the files are being saved in the debug folder of the project, I want to store the files in the appdata folder under a generic specified folder!

```
AViewModel vm = DataContext as AViewModel;
var table = vm.FileSelectedItem;

if (table != null)
{
    var filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    File.WriteAllBytes(table.FileTitle, table.Data);
    Process prc = new Process();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = table.FileTitle;
    prc.Start();
}  

//table.FileTitle is the name of the file stored in the db 
//    eg:(test1.docx, test2.pdf, test3.txt, test4.xlsx)
//table.Data is public byte[] Data { get; set; } property
//    which stores the files coming from the db.
```

I am looking at GetFolderPath and trying something like this now

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

Thanks for any replys!

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear. `filename` is never used. And it looks like you forgot to ask your question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) returns a full path to a file *in the user's temp path*.  You can't use that to create a file within a specific folder.

Given that you want to store within the `AppData` folder already, perhaps you are after something more like:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "YourCompany\\YourProduct\\Output");

var filename = Path.Combine(path, table.FileTitle);

File.WriteAllBytes(filename, table.Data);

Process.Start(filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to create randomly named file under AppData, you can try

```
 Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
```

That'll give you random string with reasonable certainty it is unique. For folder under AppData:

```
  Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
```

Note: at least put it into some subfolder, AppData is folder shared with all other apps.